# Flutter App on iOS crashes on debug after upgrading to 3.10

Tags: flutter, flutter-3.10

I recently upgraded my Flutter version to 3.10. My app is already in production and was working perfectly. After upgrading to 3.10 my app crashes just before being opened.

**Context :**

I had a perfectly running application on v3.7, I recently upgraded my Flutter version to 3.10, and the app crashes on iOS every time I try to run it. While my other few projects are working fine, one or two projects have this issue.

**What steps I did for the debugging :**

1. Checked if my app was using any backdrop filter [Got few references online about same], and it wasn't the case.
2. Carefully checked my dependencies.
3. Tried to run directly from XCode, same issue.
4. Tried checking out to master channel, still same issue.

**Verbose Logs**

```
[ +464 ms] <my_app_id>: 97998
[        ] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
    
[+4912 ms] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller     rendering backend.
    
[ +956 ms] VM Service URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:65320/QcIpu0ixOio=/
[   +8 ms] Caching compiled dill
[ +112 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:65320/QcIpu0ixOio=/
[  +20 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection
    refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 65321
[        ] This was attempt #1. Will retry in 0:00:00.100000.
```

**Expected Behavior**

App should have been properly running since it had no issues on 3.7.

Comment: Did you try to update the packages? 
There is an issue with the same error code here - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65349
which tries to blame firebase. Also I'd try to run the app with a different Wi-Fi

Comment: Yah 3.10 update was a nightmare for me too. Try flutter clean, delete your podfile.lock manually, flutter pub get, pod install - then it worked for me.

Comment: Deleting podfile.lock is likely the most important step here^